# date_query on draft posts only

Tags: wp-query

I would like to **query WordPress *draft* posts only from the past 7 days** (ie current date and looking back at the last 7 days, not looking at strictly Monday to Sunday weeks).

The problem I am facing at hand is that it **does not return me any results at all**. If I were to comment out the line that specifies the post_status, it **works on published posts only**.

**EDIT: Problem is resolved.** The issue at-hand causing no results to show up was pertaining to other parts of my code.

**EDIT2: The code below can be significantly shortened to:**

```
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'after' => '1 week ago'
    )
```

My original code is as follows:

```
$today = getdate();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'page'),
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => array(
                'year' => $today['year'],
                'month' => $today['mon'],
                'day' => ($today['mday'] - 7)
            ),
            'before' => array(
                'year' => $today['year'],
                'month' => $today['mon'],
                'day' => $today['mday']
            ),
            'inclusive' => true
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: that query seems to work fine for me, it returns draft posts within the past week. `var_dump` the query object after you run the query to see what it looks like.

Comment: Issue solved. The problem was pertaining to another part of my code. Thanks to @Milo for introducing me to var_dump which I didn't know prior to this!

Comment: Your query will fail for days like the 3rd of the month. You can't just `- 7` on that, better to use [`DateTime::modify()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

Comment: Thanks @kero for the pro-tip! That issue slipped my mind.